# Border radius for twitter bootstrap carousel doesn't work on Chrome browser

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

**Border radius for twitter bootstrap carousel works fine on Firefox and IE9 but doesn't work on Chrome browser**

```
<style>
.carousel{
    -moz-border-radius: 10px; /* FF1+ */
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* Saf3-4, iOS 1+, Android 1.5+ */
    border-radius: 10px; /* Opera 10.5, IE9, Saf5, Chrome, FF4 */
    overflow:hidden;
}
</style>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" >
    <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item">
            <img src="img/1.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/2.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/3.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Carousel nav -->
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: try adding !important to style. Like border-radius: 10px !important;

Comment: Can you post your complete code with twitter bootstrap default css.

Comment: `!important` doesn't work too

Comment: If you could post  link to your page that would help us to diagnose the problem much easier.

Comment: It's Local page @BillyMoat but you can edit it from firebug that page it has the same problem [link](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel)

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and solved increasing `z-index` of `.carousel`.

```
.carousel{
    -moz-border-radius: 10px; /* FF1+ */
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* Saf3-4, iOS 1+, Android 1.5+ */
    border-radius: 10px; /* Opera 10.5, IE9, Saf5, Chrome, FF4 */
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue.
It was due to carousel-control (control panel in order to see next/previous picture).
I had this and it works just fine for me :-)

```
.carousel img{ border-radius: 55px; }
.carousel-control { background-image:none !important; }
```