# Rounding Bootstrap 3 Carousel Corners

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to style a Bootstrap 3 carousel with CSS to have rounded corners. I am able to round the corners of the images in the carousel, but for some reason the background carousel edges remain unrounded. What am I doing wrong here?[image]

```
<style type="text/css">
.carousel {
    border-radius: 55px 55px 55px 55px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-right: 200px;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
 .carousel-caption {
    z-index: 10;
}
/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
 .carousel .item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #777;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .carousel-caption p {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        font-size: 21px;
        line-height: 1.4;
    }
}
img {
    border-radius: 55px 55px 55px 55px;
}
</style>

<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="30000" data-pause="hover">
    <!-- Menu -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="item active">
            <img src="images/image3.jpg" alt="Slide 1" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/image7.jpg" alt="Slide 2" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/image6.jpg" alt="Slide 3" />
        </div>
    </div> 
    <a href="#carousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a href="#carousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I use the browser inspector a lot. Look at the styles and properties and where they come from to find out if you are not able to get a clean answer. Try to force the styles right from there because maybe something is been overridden.

Comment: This answer is what solved the issue for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684550/border-radius-for-twitter-bootstrap-carousel-doesnt-work-on-chrome-browser

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to hide the overflow:

```css
.carousel {
    border-radius: 55px 55px 55px 55px;
    overflow: hidden;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Than you can get a problem with animations. Maybe.

Comment: @Webice nope, I tested it before answering and this doesn't affect the animation at all. You can apply the `border-radius` and `overflow` through your browser's element inspector on the official carousel example here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Comment: Not on the default animations, but when you have slide / fadeout in once the fadeout is not working.

Answer (score 5):

None of the above worked for me as the slides only got rounded after sliding, but still showed square edges on sliding. For me the following worked like a charm.

```
.carousel-inner {
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me in Bootstrap5 , thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
 .carousel .item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #777;
    border-radius: 55px 55px 55px 55px;
}
```

Add this and it should work.

Comment: Yes that should actually work. What James is suggesting shouldn't work if you don't really round the containers.

Answer (score 0):

```
.carousel-control {
 position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 15%;
opacity: .5;
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
font-size: 20px;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
border-radius: 9px; <---- or whatever 
}
```

Comment: You should add some explanation of why your answer is best, or how it works; rather than just post code alone.

Answer (score 0):

For the best, simplest solution!!!

```
.carousel .item {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-control {
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```